# Free Item with Free Shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes, free-shipping

I'm trying to make a **coupon code** that provides my giveaway winner with one free pair of socks and free shipping.

If the winner decides to add another pair of socks, I want the coupon to still give one free but charge for the other pair and then add my standard shipping charge.

I get either all of the items for free or it always gives free shipping.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use coupon code, I bet you should use "Cart Price Rule", isn't it?

```
On cart price rule->(your rule)->Actions->Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To->Set to 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried that. It gives one free for each different item in the cart. If the quantity goes to 2 or more the coupon goes away for that particular sock. I want it to limit it to only one free item no matter how many socks are in the cart.